# How to set vagrants host SSH port

Tags: ssh, vagrant, portforwarding

I have multiple VMs managed by vagrant in a production environment. I like to set their SSH host ports manually while I have to open every single port in iptables. Vagrant manages these port forwarding manually by default which forces me to open a range of ports which I doesn't want to.

I already tried a port forwarding but it ends up with two ports forwarded to the guest.

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", id: "a-named-ssh-forwarding", host: 54321, guest: 22
```

The problem is I cannot see any option in the vagrant SSH config section. Obviously I could set the guests SSH port only.

[Vagrant SSH settings](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html)

Is it even possible to set the forwarded host SSH port and if yes how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is too simple.

[Overriding the Default Forwarded SSH Port in Vagrant](https://realguess.net/2015/10/06/overriding-the-default-forwarded-ssh-port-in-vagrant/)

Just rename the ID of the forwarded port to `ssh`.

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", id: "ssh", host: 54321, guest: 22
```

This in fact removes the possibility to identify the ssh forwardings to a specific VM by reading the list. But it's a low price for the enhanced system's security.